# How to get unique list from two column in Entity Framework core?

Tags: sql, linq, lambda, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I have a Table in the database with 2 Columns containing userIds.

```
Column A
1
2
3
4
5

Column B
4
2
6
1
7
```

Now I want to get a list/array containing the distinct Ids.

The expected result will be

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Any idea how to do it?

I am looking for a Ef Core lambda/linq which will run on the database end and not have to fetch the result in the memory and then find the distinct list as that would be costly operation.

Comment: something like this

var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSql("SELECT distinct id FROM (select colA as id from tabA unionall select colB as id from tabB)")
    .ToList();

Comment: sub queries costs performance but nice approach. can you translate into linq/lamda expression

Comment: try this IList<String> ids = ((from taba in ids
                                   select ids)
                                   .Union(from tabB in ids
                                      select (ids))).ToList();

Comment: wow nice I like that approach I will use that

Comment: If that works. let me know I will add it as an answer

Comment: I want to post my answer on how I did it but I can't due to less reputation which includes your logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
var ids = Table1.Select( i => i.ColumnA )
                .Union( Table2.Select( j => j.ColumnB ) )
                .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `union`:

```
select col1
from t
union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select col2
from t;
```

You would then read the results of the query into your application.

Comment: A linq or Lambda expression will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an answer for further reference:

```
IList<String> ids = ((from taba in ids select ids) .Union(from tabB in ids select (ids))).ToList();
```